# zf2 doctrine2 relationship properties not working

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

I have following none-column properties in the user enitity

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Auth\Entity\Company", inversedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="companyID", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $company;


/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Auth\Entity\Role", inversedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="roleID", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $role;
```

I don't have column role or company in user table. 
But I do hae column roleID and companyID in user table and thier respective properties in user entity as below

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Auth\Entity\Role", inversedBy="user") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="roleID", referencedColumnName="id")    
     */
    protected $roleID;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Auth\Entity\Company", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="companyID", referencedColumnName="id")     
     */
    protected $companyID;
```

In user controller when I try to add record using following lines it adds the record successfully but without roleID and companyID

```
           $userData = array("username" => $username, "pass" => $secPass,
                "salt" => $salt, "companyID" => $companyID,
                "roleID" => $roleID, "cost" => $cost
            );


            $user->populate($userData);
            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($user);
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
```

but if I remove these two properties from entity user, then it also add roleID and companyID

```
protected $company;
protected $role;
```

but I also need above properties. I could not able to understand why is this conflict,

anyone faced this problem? and how to sort this out? any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your properties in user entity as below

```
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $roleID;

/**
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $companyID;


/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Auth\Entity\Company", inversedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="companyID", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $company;


/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Auth\Entity\Role", inversedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="roleID", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $role;
```

and then in your user controller do following to add. it worked for me

```
 $company = $this->getEntityManager()->find('Auth\Entity\Company', $companyID);                
    $role = $this->getEntityManager()->find('Auth\Entity\Role', $roleID);                

    $user->username = $username;
    $user->pass = $secPass;
    $user->salt = $salt;
    $user->company = $company;
    $user->role = $role;
    $user->cost = $cost;                

    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($user);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
```

Comment: AFAIK, you should never have ids in your entity properties.

Comment: You don't need to map these colums `$companyID` and `$roleID`, you can use `$this->company->getId()` and `$this->role->getId()`. You can also create proxy methods in your entity if you need it frequently.